# Ubuntu - Security - Sudo disable password :: What difference in security if sudo will not requere password?

Tags: ubuntu, security, ubuntu-10.04

What difference in security of UBUNTU if sudo will not require password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone with access to your machine while logged in but not locked will be able to use sudo to have commands executed as root, as opposed to only being able to act like you.

Comment: soo if i dont have network only internet I can disable password for sudo, right?

Comment: Having to enter a password for sudo has nothing to do with a network. It's access to a shell on your machine as you that matters.

Comment: @meyosef: No, I'd not recommend such a thing. One of the best things of Linux if it comes to counterfeiting malware and viruses is it's strict permission management system. Deactivating the sudo password is like surfing under Windows XP with the Admin-Account. Everybody who gets access, can do anything with your machine then. Though, getting access is way harder...it's a bad idea none the less.